# DB2 - stored procedure - very slow cursor when using IN parameter in fetch first clause

Tags: performance, db2, cursor, db2-luw

Version: db2 11.5 / AIX.

**SLOW:** (Using IN parameter)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_INC (IN nINC INTEGER)
BEGIN
   FOR EACH_RECORD AS C1 CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT * 
      FROM MYTABLE 
      WHERE SEQ > 0 
      ORDER BY SEQ FETCH FIRST nINC ROWS ONLY
   DO
   ...
   END FOR;
END;
```

**FAST** (Using a fixed value)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_INC (IN nINC INTEGER)
BEGIN
   FOR EACH_RECORD AS C1 CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT * 
      FROM MYTABLE 
      WHERE SEQ > 0 
      ORDER BY SEQ FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
   DO
   ...
   END FOR
END;
```

Can anybody help me?

I would like, if possible, to continue using `FOR`.

Comment: In Db2, the `fetch first` clause can __only__ mention a constant (i.e. a fixed value).  You should get a syntax error if you try to specify a host variable instead of a fixed value.    Your should edit your question to specify your exact Db2-version and your Db2-server platform (z/os, linux/unix/windows,  i-series etc).  Always give these details when you ask for help with Db2.

Comment: There is no error during creation and execution, but it is extremely slow, as if the entire table loaded more than 200 million rows, but in fact it only brings the quantity informed in the parameter.

Comment: Is it possible to use dynamic query with FOR command?

Comment: I'm sorry, 11.5 (AIX). I put it in the message.

Comment: Can you post the execution plans of both queries to compare? You can use my site for DB2: [Check The Plan](https://checktheplan.com/?engine=db2luw).